# 32gig sd card corrupt

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, external-sd, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover data from a damaged SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21141/how-to-recover-data-from-a-damaged-sd-card)

I have a 32Gb micro SD card that I've solely used for my Samsung Galaxy S3.  The card has been completely cleared and is not recognizable to the phone.

I took a few pic of my daughter, plugged the phone in to charge and went to bed.  This morning when I got to work the phone indicated that it was safe to remove the memory card. I didn't prompt this so I restarted the phone and went to send a pic after it started up again but noticed all my pics and vids were gone.

Is there something that I can do to recover the files or does anyone know if there is a reason that this has happened?

Comment: There are already a couple of similar questions which might prove helpful: [How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/), [How to recover data from a damaged SD card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21141/), [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/).

Comment: You may also want to [check that your memory card isn't a fake](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/29649/4229), which can also lead to what *appears to be* corruption.

Answer (score 2):

Try accessing the memory card from another device or a memory card reader connected to a computer. If it still looks empty, you can use data recovery software on the card to try to extract any useful data. There's plenty of apps available for this, so you'd have to search for something suitable to your OS and your budget (some of them cost money) - look for articles like [5 of the Best Free Linux Data Recovery Tools](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20100226122928107/DataRecovery.html).

If you find that your card works flawlessly in another card reader, then your phone is likely at fault and should be returned for a replacement.

If you manage to recover data from the apparently empty card, you should probably replace it as soon as possible as it doesn't seem to be completely reliable.